# Codenameone HTMLParser gives NPE

Tags: codenameone

I am constantly getting a NPE while trying to parse a basic html string using the HTMLParser.
Code:

```
    String html = "<html><body>Test</body></html>";
    HTMLParser parser = new HTMLParser();
    System.out.println(parser);
    ByteArrayInputStream ba = new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes());
    System.out.println("ba::" + ba);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(ba);
    System.out.println("isr1::" + isr);                
    HTMLElement root = parser.parseHTML(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(html.getBytes())));        
    Hashtable data = root.getAttributes();
    Set kys = data.keySet();
    for (Object o : kys) {
        System.out.println("key::" + (String) o);
        System.out.println("value::" + (String) data.get(o));
    }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.codename1.ui.html.HTMLParser.parseTagContent(HTMLParser.java:81)
at com.codename1.xml.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:267)
at com.codename1.ui.html.HTMLParser.parseHTML(HTMLParser.java:174)
at userclasses.StateMachine.beforeMain(StateMachine.java:52)
```

Am I doing anything wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `XMLParser`. The `HTMLParser` is designed for use in the `HTMLComponent`.